# Rails using child value in a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, nested-forms, model-associations

So, I have a nested form where Shelter has many Cats (just using cats as an example to melt the hearts of those eager to help).

So, in my nested form I can use:

```
<%= f.object.shelter_id %>
```

which gives a value when I run the application. But, and here is the cute cat's but:

```
<%= f.object.shelter.name %>
```

doesn't work, nor does:

```
<%= Shelter.find(f.object.shelter_id).name %>
```

Above statement gives an error can't find Shelter where 'id'=

One would think the value would be passed to the query as it is displayed when the app is run? How do I access the associated values in the form? (Its only in Edit, my Show and other controllers and views work fine.)

And yes, the associations are declared in my models.

Comment: Do you have `inverse_of` option set also in the association?

Comment: Yes I do have it set

Comment: seems like `f.object.shelter_id` is `nil`

Comment: @pav, like i mentioned above, it has a value...

Comment: @doer123456789 Can you add `<%= puts "shelted_id: #{f.object.shelter_id}" %>` just above `<%= Shelter.find(f.object.shelter_id).name %>`, and then check the output in the console? Because the error you're getting: `can't find Shelter where 'id'=` means that `nil` is passed into `find()`, or... if you're error message is incomplete and that you instead should have written: `can't find Shelter where 'id'=12345`, then it means that a `Shelter` record with id==12345 does not exist in the DB.